While Reading excel file into array, exit the FileReader's onload function if the excel file is empty using JavaScript
I want to show a alert message and exit the FileReader onload function if there is no records or the excel is empty
$(document).on('change', '#InputFile', function(evt) {
  var regexExcel = /(\.xlsx|\.xls)$/i;
  var file = evt.target.files[0];

  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
      type: 'array'
    }); // Parse the data as Excel file

    var firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0]; // name of the sheet
    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName]; // Get the first sheet
    var excelData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
      header: 1
    }); // Convert the sheet to JSON data

    console.log(excelData);
    if (excelData.length == 0) {
      $(".global-loader").hide();
      $("#UploadData .error-txt").show().text("No records found in the selected Excel file");
      $('#InputFile').val('');
      return;
    }

    excelData = excelData.filter(row => row.some(cell => !!cell));
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});

I have tried this to return from the function :
if (excelData.length == 0) {
  $(".global-loader").hide();
  $("#UploadData .error-txt").show().text("No records found in the selected Excel file");
  $('#InputFile').val('');
  return;
}

But this is not working. How to achieve this?

So what did the console.log(excelData) result in then? Also, what is XLSX.read - please mention/tag what library you are using there.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.3/xlsx.full.min.js , https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/read-excel-file/6.3.0/read-excel-file.min.js
console.log(excelData) result is -> [
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[]
]

So the length is 38, not 0. All the elements are zero-length arrays, though.

You could use if (excelData.every(el => el.length == 0))
